# Passing consistent-type-assertions without hurting brevity?

Tags: typescript, eslint

A project I'm on has decided to warn on `typescript-eslint/consistent-type-assertions` with options `{ assertionStyle: 'as', objectLiteralTypeAssertions: 'never' }`. Most of the time I like its recommendations. But it can make lambda's too verbose. Compare the following:

```
x.map((y) => ({ name: 'name', id: 'id' } as SomeType));
```

and

```
x.map((y) => {
    const item: SomeType = { name: 'name', id: 'id' };
    return item;
});
```

I prefer the first for it's brevity. It is especially preferable when chaining a lot of functions together.

Is there anyway to satisfy `typescript-eslint/consistent-type-assertions` in this case without introducing a temporary variable and an extra code block with a `return`?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can simply specify the return type of the arrow function.

```
type SomeType = { name: string; id: string; admin?: boolean };

const names = ["Alice", "Bob"];

const objects = names.map((el): SomeType => ({ name: el, id: "id" }));
//    ^?const objects: SomeType[]
```